# Any way to speed up Picasa PhotoQuery?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, image-gallery, picasa

I am trying to retrieve a couple sets of images from Picasa via `C#`.  When I debug, I notice that the queries are taking up to 4 seconds each.  My code is as follows:

```
var thumbnailPhotoQuery = new PhotoQuery(PicasaQuery.CreatePicasaUri("SomeUser","SomeGallery"));
var largePhotoQuery = new PhotoQuery(PicasaQuery.CreatePicasaUri("SomeUser","AnotherGallery"));

var thumbnailFeed = picasaService.Query(thumbnailPhotoQuery);
var largeFeed = picasaService.Query(largePhotoQuery);
```

My galleries contain only about 20 images each.  Is there anything I can do to make these execute faster?

Answer (score 0):

try specify what do you really want to download using "fields" extra parameter.

Example:

```
thumbnailPhotoQuery.ExtraParameters = @"fields=entry(gphoto:id,title,gphoto:"
+ "timestamp,media:group(media:content,media:thumbnail[@width=144]))";
```